# C# Programmatically close down other processes based on their CPU/Memory usage

Tags: c#, windows, process, console-application

I have a scraping bot, that was developed a while back by a company for us, and it's used to scrape some data off of a lot of websites.

The problem lately is that the bot fires off "faulty" threads, that have a really bad impact on the overall performance.

We can't redo the scraping bot right now, so I was looking for alternatives, and I found out, that if I manually end the faulty processes in Task Manager, then the rest of the processes don't get impacted, and program will continue to work nicely.

I also looked at the statistics and usage metrics of each running process, and I think I came to the conclusion, that the faulty processes use 0 disk IO, and a lot less RAM, than the normal processes.

Based on these assumptions, could I be able to close down these faulty processes programmatically, with a console application, that runs ever 5-10 minutes (called via Task Scheduler)?

**Additionally**, the bot sometimes throws up a Selenium error which says:

> The HTTP request to the remote WebDriver timed out after 60 seconds

Could my console application also press the **OK** button on this MessageBox? (here I'm not able to tell which process threw up the error)

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills Hi, and thanks for the reply! 
Sadly, I can't add a code example from the scraping program, cause I only have the executable. If I was able to get to the source code, I wouldn't have this issue, cause I would correct it there. With this question, I'm basically asking if it is possible to sort out, and pick out a process with a certain RAM/CPU/Disk usage.

Comment: It is possible, yes.